# What is the keyboard sequence to fill in API function in QtCreator IDE?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am having problem googling for this topic.  I am working with QtCreator.  Whenever I type in a method, the IDE will display a list of suitable methods in a list.  If I select one of the methods, the IDE will auto complete that method.  The problem I have is that it does not put in the all parameters for that method.   What I mean by that is if I select
mouseMoveEvent, the IDE will autocomplete

```
   mouseMoveEvent() instead of
   mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsMouseMoveEvent event);
```

I know this can be done but I can't seem to find the right topic.  Does anyone know the key sequence to do this?.   Thanks.

BTW:  I am using a Mac, I don't know if that makes any differences.

Comment: If you declare it the first time there is nothing to complete. For defining creator has cool tools that automate that process. Well the type specifier is only needed for declarations and definitions. For usage of the function you dont need typespecifiers :D

Answer (score 0):

First type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, then navigate between the available method using <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd>.

Since it is the same that [spotlight](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight), I changed spotlight shortcut.

Comment: Hi Martin, I don't understand what you mean by spotlight.  Whenever I press ctrl+space it brings up the list and when I select the item from the list, it does not fill in the parameters.  It just have the empty brackets.  This is how it works on the mac.  I don't know if it is different on other platform.

Comment: Spotlight is macos search system (accessible by the magnifing glass icon in the upper right corner).

Comment: Just to make sure: what is your use case? Adding a method to a class or calling a method?

Comment: I am adding a method to the header file.  The method is supposed to override the existing base method.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured the key sequence for this.  ctrl+space to bring up the list.   Press CAP-LOCK, press Tab will go to the parameter list and press Return.